# Temporarily disable showing autofill values in input fields while recording screen capture video

Tags: html, video-capture, autofill

I am screen recording a "How to video" and would like to temporarily disable autofill values being shown in input fields while I am doing the recording. They keep popping up when I click a input field during recording and it spoils the video because I don't want to show them.

Comment: after loading the html page, use devtools to insert the `autocomplete="false"` attribute.

Comment: I guess most browsers have profile managements. At least Chrome and Firefox have it. Use a new profile.

Comment: Perfect. Profiles will work for my need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

make your input autocomplete off like below:

```html
<input type"text" autocomplete="off">
```